# DownloadFileAsync shows as completed but no file exists in specified directory

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download

I am using:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Selected.url), fh.tempFolder);
```

To download a file with a url that i know works. `fh.tempFolder` is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\FileStoreTemp` and i have even updated the manifest to elevate the application to the highest available user level, yet the file does not download to the location.

The `DownloadFileCompleted` event fires, but when i debug and step through, it appears as though the download goes immediately from start to completed, which shouldnt happen as the file is a few hundred MB in size, and so some time would be needed to download it.

I have even tried changing the download location to the desktop and still it does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the folder AND the file name for destination in the method `DownloadFileAsync`. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144197%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string tempFolder = @"C:\temp\";
client.DownloadFileAsync("test.com\test.txt",tempFolder); // won't work
client.DownloadFileAsync("test.com\test.txt",tempFolder + "test.txt"); // works
```

Comment: Wow i feel like a dunce for not realising that!! Thanks!

Comment: @Bahaïka that's exactly what I'm saying in the comment in my code example, but it's doesn't seem like he get it :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DownloadFile`

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(link, path);
//you will have to specify the filename for path
//for example: myTmpFolder/downloadFile.pdf
```

Not specifying the filename in you `fh.tmpFolder` could be the reason why you're not downloading the file, but I'm not 100% certain because I have not been using `DownloadFileAsync`

**--EDIT--**

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Selected.url), @"C:\Users*****\Desktop\downloadFile.txt"); //specify the filename
```

Comment: even when i use `client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Selected.url), @"C:\Users\*****\Desktop");` i have the same issue

Comment: @sh3rifme did you specify the filename in your path? not just the path to the directory, but a filename also. Just want to double check because the example you provided does not have filename.

Comment: @sh3rifme try something like this client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Selected.url), @"C:\Users\*****\Desktop\downloadFile.txt"); or if you know the exact file extension then use that instead.